# Installing 'traffic' for use in JupyterLab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, traffic

It is not possible for me to install the python library 'traffic' and get it running.

I'm trying to install the traffic library for python. So far, nothing has worked out. 
When using `pip install traffic` the error "Could not build wheels for Cartopy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects" is generated. 
The command `conda create -n traffic -c conda-forge python=3.9.7 traffic` the installation is running several hours and evetually terminated. 
I already downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio and ran `conda create ...` in there. The same error message came up.

Does anyone know how to install the traffic library

Comment: it happens sometimes, have u tried reinstalling/upgrading python to latest version?

Comment: @EvilReboot thanks for the hint! I just updated python to version 3.9.15 and tried 'conda create ... ' as well 'pip install traffic' again. Unfortunately again without success. Do you happen to know another approach?

Comment: why don't you download the package from pip and install it via manually

Comment: because I don't really how to do this